using fp16 in "to cuda" function call, of a HuggingFace pipeline does not work
it works if i load the model using fp16, so not using variant i assumed that the model is being converted to fp16
pipe = PixArtAlphaPipeline.from_pretrained(MODEL_ID, torch_dtype=torch.float16)
pipe.to("cuda")

however when i use this one:
pipe = PixArtAlphaPipeline.from_pretrained(MODEL_ID)
pipe.to("cuda", dtype=torch.float16)

it does not work - it loads the model but it generates only garbage.
what is the difference between the 2? i would assume that both are converting the model to fp16.
here the complete code:
import torch
from diffusers import PixArtAlphaPipeline
import os

output_dir = "./generated/"
if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
    os.mkdir(output_dir)

prompt = "A small cactus with a happy face in the Sahara desert."

# Create a pipeline with float32 weights and move it to the GPU, convert it to float16 using .to()
pipe1 = PixArtAlphaPipeline.from_pretrained("PixArt-alpha/PixArt-XL-2-512x512")
pipe1.to("cuda", dtype=torch.float16)

image = pipe1(prompt, width=512, height=512, num_inference_steps=20).images[0]
image.save(os.path.join(output_dir, "1.png"))

del pipe1

# Create a pipeline with float16 weights and move it to the GPU
pipe2 = PixArtAlphaPipeline.from_pretrained("PixArt-alpha/PixArt-XL-2-512x512", torch_dtype=torch.float16)
pipe2.to("cuda")

image = pipe2(prompt, width=512, height=512, num_inference_steps=20).images[0]
image.save(os.path.join(output_dir, "2.png"))

the requirements file:
transformers
accelerate
diffusers[torch]
sentencepiece
beautifulsoup4
# --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121
torch
torchvision


Can you provide a minimal example to reproduce this error, right now you only describe that the latter produces "garbage" but we cannot test that.

i have just added it. 2.png is ok, 1.png is garbage

That is your description of what is happening, not a minimal reproducible example, ie. we can't reproduce it. Please edit your question.

if you take that code and run in, you can actually reproduce the problem. it is the description + the code to run it
